# How to access data within the multi index format of a Bloomberg API call

Tags: python, pandas, bloomberg

I'm building a trade backtest app and have managed to get the data in jupyter notebook using pdblp. However, the data is multi-level and I don't know enough about data frames to properly unpack it.

What I need is to be able to access **df[PX_LAST]** which should be the same regardless of the stock used. It is not that simple as df.keys() produces

```
MultiIndex(levels=[['AHT LN Equity'], ['BEST_PE_RATIO', 'PX_LAST']],
       labels=[[0, 0], [1, 0]],
       names=['ticker', 'field'])
```

I've tried

> df = pd.DataFrame(df.to_records())

but this results in messy titles and I have had issues changing the name.

```
import pdblp

con = pdblp.BCon(debug=False, port=8194, timeout=5000)

con.start()

df = con.bdh('AHT LN Equity', ['PX_LAST', 'BEST_PE_RATIO'], '20190102', '20190331')
```

I've tried

> df1=df.unstack(level=1).reset_index()

which didn't work, and

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(df.to_records())
```

the latter partially worked but is tricky as I want to rename the column to something without the ticker and also having issues with the apostrophes I guess as rename failed.

```
df.rename(columns={'('AHT LN Equity', 'PX_LAST')': 'Close'},      inplace=True)

File "<ipython-input-37-7677eac9ff45>", line 2
df.rename(columns={'('AHT LN Equity', 'PX_LAST')': 'Close'}, inplace=True)
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Few examples you can play around with [`xbbg`](https://xbbg.readthedocs.io):

```
In [1]: from xbbg import blp
In [2]: df = blp.bdh(['AHT LN Equity', 'AGK LN Equity'], ['PX_LAST', 'BEST_PE_RATIO'], start_date='20190102', end_date='20190331')
In [3]: df.tail()
Out[3]:
ticker     AHT LN Equity               AGK LN Equity
field            PX_LAST BEST_PE_RATIO       PX_LAST BEST_PE_RATIO
2019-03-25      1,827.50         11.09        749.96         14.62
2019-03-26      1,805.50         10.96        755.63         14.73
2019-03-27      1,809.00         10.98        751.52         14.71
2019-03-28      1,827.50         11.09        753.48         14.74
2019-03-29      1,852.50         11.24        770.71         15.08
```

To quote `PX_LAST`, you can:

```
In [4]: df.xs('PX_LAST', axis=1, level=1).tail()
Out[4]:
ticker      AHT LN Equity  AGK LN Equity
2019-03-25       1,827.50         749.96
2019-03-26       1,805.50         755.63
2019-03-27       1,809.00         751.52
2019-03-28       1,827.50         753.48
2019-03-29       1,852.50         770.71
```

To quote data for `AHT LN Equity`, you can either:

```
In [5]: df['AHT LN Equity'].tail()
Out[5]:
field       PX_LAST  BEST_PE_RATIO
2019-03-25 1,827.50          11.09
2019-03-26 1,805.50          10.96
2019-03-27 1,809.00          10.98
2019-03-28 1,827.50          11.09
2019-03-29 1,852.50          11.24
```

or

```
In [6]: df.loc[:, 'AHT LN Equity'].tail()
Out[6]:
field       PX_LAST  BEST_PE_RATIO
2019-03-25 1,827.50          11.09
2019-03-26 1,805.50          10.96
2019-03-27 1,809.00          10.98
2019-03-28 1,827.50          11.09
2019-03-29 1,852.50          11.24
```

To quote `BEST_PE_RATIO` of `AHT LN Equity`, you can either (notice the minor differences in the name of the `Series`):

```
In [7]: df['AHT LN Equity']['BEST_PE_RATIO'].tail()
Out[7]:
2019-03-25   11.09
2019-03-26   10.96
2019-03-27   10.98
2019-03-28   11.09
2019-03-29   11.24
Name: BEST_PE_RATIO, dtype: float64
```

or

```
In [8]: df[('AHT LN Equity', 'BEST_PE_RATIO')].tail()
Out[8]:
2019-03-25   11.09
2019-03-26   10.96
2019-03-27   10.98
2019-03-28   11.09
2019-03-29   11.24
Name: (AHT LN Equity, BEST_PE_RATIO), dtype: float64
```

Comment: thanks for this very helpful- I used pdblp and then just did df1 = df.loc[:, AHT LN Equity]. That solved the multi index problem. This is a big issue because in raw format you can't for for loops, if statements etc. Now have made it work so much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use [pd.IndexSlice](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.IndexSlice.html)

when trying to slice a column or index in a multiindex, pd.IndexSlice is very efficient.

```
# set idx for ease of use.
idx = pd.IndexSlice
```

The slice using .loc

```
# if you are slicing in the column
df.loc[:, idx[:,'PX_LAST']]

# if you have more than one item in level 1
df.loc[:, idx[:,['BEST_PE_RATIO','PX_LAST']]

# if you wish to add slice up one level
df.loc[:, idx['AHT LN Equity','BEST_PE_RATIO']]

# if you are slicing in the index
df.loc[idx[:,'SOME_INDEX'],:]

# if you are slicing in both index and column
df.loc[idx[:,'SOME_INDEX'], idx[:,'PX_LAST']]
```